# Grafana - display 3 values on BarChart

Tags: grafana

I would like to represent 3 values in Grafana using BarChart. I'm using PostgreSQL as DataSource. I'm using this query: `SELECT commit, ticket, (max(endtime) - min(starttime))/1000 as deploy_time FROM public.testmetrics WHERE ticket IN ('PS-1234') GROUP BY ticket, commit;` which returns:

```
commit  | ticket  | deploy_time
-----------------------------
cda713  | PS-1234 |  65313
asd2137 | PS-1234 |  110
```

In Grafana I'm using this query: `SELECT commit, ticket, (max(endtime) - min(starttime))/1000 as deploy_time FROM public.testmetrics WHERE ticket IN ($PR) GROUP BY ticket, commit;`

In case of ticket `PS-1234` I'm getting this:

[image]

I would like to display also a ticket (close to commit or on bar). When I switch view to table I can see all the value, but is there a chance to see it also on chart?

**UPDATE 1**

After changing bar type to `Bar gauge` it looks like this:

[image]

First weird - some commits are displayed in format like a date/time. Second, is there a way to move tickets to right or to make them more visible?

Comment: I don't think that *Bar chart/ is a correct panel for what you are doing. Consider using *Bar gauge* instead (with selected option **All values** in Value option > Show).

Comment: @markalex  for sure it did good job, but I notice some weird behavior - see update

Comment: Regarding unexpected format: you probably used some format change option, and allowed it be applied to all numbers. This affected commits represented only by digits.

Comment: And regarding ticket visibility: what you got is a default view for Bar gauges, and it's not particularly customizable (at least for sql data sources). If you want even more options for shuffling things around (but keeping some kind of gauge view), consider [this demo for table panel with gauges in cells](https://play.grafana.org/d/OhR1ID6Mk/3-table?orgId=1&viewPanel=12)